# return View does not work properly

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, view

I want to redirect to another View of same controller from a function of controller.

Here is my code
In view :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("CreateEBulletinPdf","EBulletin")',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "productIdList": selectedProductIdList }),
    success: function (result) {

    }
});
```

In Controller :

```
public void CreateEBulletinPdf(string productIdList)
{             
    productIdList = productIdList.Substring(0, productIdList.Length - 1);

    var productIdStrings = productIdList.Split(',');

    detailViewModels = productIdStrings.Select(productIdString => PdfProduct(Convert.ToInt32(productIdString))).ToList();

    ProductsEBulletin();                             
}

public ActionResult ProductsEBulletin()
{
    try
    {
        return View(detailViewModels);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {   
        throw;
    }
}
```

After all my functions run, my target view which name is ProductsEBulletin does not shown. Where is my mistake ?

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint, debugged your code and verified, that it is called and working?

Comment: Your HTTP request is dispatched by the `CreateEBulletinPdf()` that doesn't return anything (`void`). Internally, it does call `ProductsEBulletin()` (that returns `ActionResult`) but `CreateEBulletinPdf` doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: @Marco, yes I debugged my code everything is ok..

Comment: I wanted to point out, that you are trying to do a post to a void, not an ActionResult and you have not decorated your ActionResult to accept a POST request

Comment: Just change the method to `public ActionResult CreateEBulletinPdf(string productIdList)` and replace `ProductsEBulletin()` with `return ProductsEBulletin()`; so it returns a result (a `void` method does not return anything)

Comment: Note it also needs to be `dataType: "html",` since your returning a view, not json (and note that you can delete `contentType: "application/json,` and just use `data: { "productIdList": selectedProductIdList },`

Comment: But you not doing anything with the view you return back to the client - add `$(someElement).html(result);` inside the success callback to display the view in the page (and you should be returning a partial view, not a view)

Answer (score 3):

First, if your making an `ajax` call with content-type `contentType: "JSON"`, no need to stringify the data object like you do here `data: JSON.stringify({ "productIdList": selectedProductIdList }),`. And since you are expecting to get `HTML` as return you need to specify the `dataType: 'html'`

Second, your `CreateEBulletinPdf` method is not returning a value so replace the last statement with `return ProductsEBulletin();`.

Last, the way your calling the action from the ajax won't work as expected, you need an action result of `JsonResult` instead of `ActionResult` to return pure `HTML`, and then insert it to your `HTML` in the `success` function of the `ajax`, as this:

Action code:

```
public JsonResult ProductsEBulletin()
{
    try
    {
        var data = RenderRazorViewToString("ProductsEBulletin", detailViewModels)
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
  ViewData.Model = model;
  using (var sw = new StringWriter())
  {
    var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext,
                                                             viewName);
    var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View,
                                 ViewData, TempData, sw);
    viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
    viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
    return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
  }
}
```

Javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("CreateEBulletinPdf","EBulletin")',
    contentType: "application/json", // type of data sent to server
    dataType: "html", // type of data received from server
    data: { "productIdList": selectedProductIdList },
    success: function (result) {
          $('#selector-of-tag-to-be-filled').html(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer is more comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks your answer. I changed my code according to your suggestions. Right now my post is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Any errors? Any details?
Kindly provide anything useful so I can help you :)